# Images that are on the IMGUR server can not be viewed

Tags: support

Here in my company there is a policy that limits me to seeing certain websites, which, to a certain extent, I agree. Unfortunately, images that are on the IMGUR server (https://i.stack.imgur.com) can not be viewed. I tried a technique where I add the term "cache:" at the beginning of the page address to try to see something, but I did not succeed.

Anyway, is there any technique that I can navigate and see the images? I do not think it is going against company policy, but there must be an unnecessary lock.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid if your company blocks imgur.com there is little to be done. SE won't change the way it hosts images and your company blocks imgur, so both endpoints are rather fixed. You may consider using the Stack Exchange App to navigate to those specific questions and see the pictures via your phone.

Since your phone is most likely not blocked by your company you should be able to see the pictures there.